# How to forbide to kill the app while writing to file continue

Tags: java, android, serialization, file-writing

My app uses the serialization to store data. Save() function is called in Activity the onStop() method. Since the data was small, everything was fine. Today serialization takes a time, and I was surpised to find a way to corrupt the data.

If I exit from the app by Home button, then quickly manually kill the app form backround activities screen (on long home button tap), my data seems to be lost. I think its because app was written to file and was interrupted.

Is there an opportunity to forbide to kill the process until my save() method works? I was thinking to rewrite serialisation by myself, and it can be faster in times, but as I understand sometimes this problem will happen again.

Thank you.

// Activity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop(){
        try {
            ms.save();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

// Singleton save fucntion

 public void save() throws IOException {
                Runnable r = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos;
                            ObjectOutputStream os;
                            if (data != null){
                                fos = context.openFileOutput("Data.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                                os.writeObject(data);
                                os.flush();
                                os.close();
                                fos.close();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.start();

    }
```

Comment: I would thinking about creating a background service to get this task done.

Comment: Are you about IntentService? Ok, I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: I check this. IntentService was killed with the app killing. =(

Comment: What was returned in your onStartCommand? It must be START_NOT_STICKY, otherwise your service will be restarted when app get killed.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! I got it. Have to use startForeground() to save service behind the app.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it using the IntentService in Background. Thanks to RyanB for the help.

save() in Singleton:

```
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceDatastore.class);
        mServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse("dsf"));
        context.startService(mServiceIntent);
```

ServiceDatastore.java

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        final int myID = 1234;
        Intent intent = new Intent(); // empty Intent to do nothing in case we click on notification.
        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification notice = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getString(R.string.saving), System.currentTimeMillis());
        notice.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Saving...", "", pendIntent);

        notice.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(myID, notice);

        try {
            Singleton ms = Singleton.getInstance(this);
            FileOutputStream fos;
            ObjectOutputStream os;
            //copy settings
            if (ms.data != null) {
                fos = this.openFileOutput("Data.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                os.writeObject(ms.data);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopForeground(true); // to kill the process if the app was killed.
    }
```